# How can I show an added node immediately in QtreeView?

Tags: qt, tree

When I expand node everythig works well:

```
void DTree::expand(const QModelIndex & index){
  if (treeModel->hasChildren(index)) return;
  DNode &node = *static_cast<DNode*>(index.internalPointer());
  qint32 size = node.makeChildren();
  treeModel->beginInsertRows(index, 0, size);
  treeModel->endInsertRows();
  setExpanded(index, true);
}
```

But when I try to show a node in its method it fails:

```
qint64 DNode::ins(){
.... some code of adding to database a new node
// here I try to make node show. ord() - new node's order in DB which starts with 1
  treeModel->beginInsertRows(treeModel->createIndex(parent->ord() - 1, 0,
    parent), ord() - 1, ord() - 1);
  treeModel->endInsertRows();
........  
}
```

I tried to use QPersistentModelIndex - in vain.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am just curious, how do you call protected function `beginInsertRows` of your model?

Comment: I've just overriden them special for such cases:

void TreeModel::beginResetModel(){QAbstractItemModel::beginResetModel();}
void TreeModel::endResetModel(){
  QAbstractItemModel::endResetModel();}

Did I do something wrong? Why?

Comment: You are right! Expand works without beginInsertRows and endInsertRows(); But I still don't know what to do.